# How to calculate % change with GLM Poisson output

Tags: r, glm, poisson, glmmtmb

Background: I have count data (beetle count) and I am looking at the effects of a gradient of a treatment on the count data. The gradient is a continuous predictor variable that consists of "7 levels" (i.e., -100% reduction, -80% reduction, -60% reduction, -40% reduction, -20% reduction, 0% reduction and 50% addition). The '0% reduction' means no change, or that is the control. I would like to compare the treatment '-60% reduction' (for example) to '0% reduction' using the GLM output.

How can I use the GLMM output with poisson distribution and log link in R to calculate the % change in count data between '-60% reduction' and '0% reduction'?

This is a sample of the model:

```
glmmTMB(count_data ~ continuous_predictor + (1|random_effect),
        family=poisson(link=log), data=data)
```

| plot number | treatment | beetle count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -60 | 4 |
| 2 | -20 | 13 |
| 3 | 0 | 23 |
| 4 | -100 | 2 |
| 5 | 50 | 10 |
| 6 | -80 | 3 |
| 7 | -40 | 5 |
| 8 | 0 | 14 |
| 9 | -20 | 9 |
| 10 | -60 | 7 |
| 11 | -100 | 1 |
| 12 | -40 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make your example reproducible first:

```r
library(glmmTMB)

data <- structure(list(
  plot_number  = 1:12, 
  treatment    = c(-60L, -20L, 0L, -100L, 50L, -80L, 
                   -40L, 0L, -20L, -60L, -100L, -40L), 
  beetle_count = c(4L, 13L, 23L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 
                   9L, 7L, 1L, 2L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

The model you describe with the data you provided looks like this:

```r
model <- glmmTMB(beetle_count ~ treatment + (1|plot_number),
                 family = poisson(link = log), 
                 data = data)

summary(model)
#>  Family: poisson  ( log )
#> Formula:          beetle_count ~ treatment + (1 | plot_number)
#> Data: data
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>     68.4     69.8    -31.2     62.4        9 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>  Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  plot_number (Intercept) 0.1703   0.4127  
#> Number of obs: 12, groups:  plot_number, 12
#> 
#> Conditional model:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) 2.366465   0.201081  11.769  < 2e-16 ***
#> treatment   0.015117   0.004148   3.645 0.000268 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

What this means is that if we wish to estimate the `beetle_count` for a given value of `treatment`, we need to calculate `exp(2.366465 + 0.015117 * treatment)`. Note that when treatment is 0, this simplifies to `exp(2.366465)` or 10.65964. For a treatment value of -60, the value is `exp(2.366465 + 0.015117 * -60)` or 4.30357.

So the expected count has dropped from 10.65964 to 4.30357, which means the percentage drop is

```r
100 * ((10.65964 - 4.30357) / 10.65964)
#> [1] 59.62744
```

Which is almost bang-on 60%

If you want to explore the percentage difference between treatment levels (let's call them `treatment_A` and `treatment_B`), the formula simplifies to

```r
100 * (1 - exp(0.015117)^(treatment_A - treatment_B))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @AllanCameron. If I can ask a follow up question, what happens when I add an interaction between treatment*categorical variable of two levels in the model? How would you calculate the % for each of these two levels of the categorical variable?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to use the `predict` function on your model, like `predict(model, newdata = data.frame(plot_number = 1, treatment = 0, categorical = c("category1", "category2")), type = "response")`. This will give you the estimated counts for any values you want to enter for the categorical and treatment variables. You can work out the percentage change from there.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Allan Cameron! But in this case, I am looking for one value for category1 and one for category2 at treatment 0. This function will give me a number for each plot, though. How do you get to one value for each category when you have multiple random effects?